# Convergence of a sequence s.t. $u_{n+1}-u_n\leq \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm looking for an simple proof of the following fact :

> Let $(u_n)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ be a sequence of non-negative real
> numbers satisfaying :  $$\forall n\in \mathbb N, \quad u_{n+1}-u_n\leq \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}$$ Then $(u_n)$ is convergent.

I know that $(u_n)$ is bounded since $$\forall n\in \mathbb N, u_n\geq 0 \quad \text{ and } \quad u_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(u_{k+1}-u_k\right) + u_0 \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k^2} + u_0\leq \dfrac{\pi^2}{6}+u_0.$$

One could consider the set $A=\{n\in \mathbb N \ | \ u_{n+1}-u_n\geq 0\}$ in order to argue about increasing or decreasing subsequences, but it seems to technical.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$u_{n+1}-u_n\leq \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^2}<\frac1{n(n+1)}=\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}$$ implies $$u_{n+1}+\frac1{n+1}-\left(u_n+\frac1n\right)<0,$$ i.e. $u_n+\frac1n$ is a decreasing positive sequence, and thus convergent.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for !